# Adding nofollow to a PHP generated Nav

Tags: php, pagination, woocommerce-offtopic, nofollow

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $wp_query;

if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array(
            'base'         => str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( 999999999 ) ),
            'format'       => '',
            'current'      => max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) ),
            'total'        => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
            'prev_text'    => '&larr;' ,
            'next_text'    => '&rarr;',
            'type'         => 'list',
            'end_size'     => 3,
            'mid_size'     => 3
        ) ) );
    ?> 
</nav>
```

I need to add *Nofollow* to the list items generated in this PHP script. How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

A simple `str_replace` would do the trick:

```
$links = paginate_links( $arguments );
$links = str_replace( 'href="', 'rel="nofollow" href="', $links );

echo $links;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want full control over the output you can use the type "array" which will instruct the `paginate_links()` function to produce and array, then you can do whatever you want with it, [see the function documentation](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2372).

```
$links = paginate_links( 
        '...'    => '...',
        '...'    => '...',
        'type'   => 'array',
        '...'    => '...',
        '...'    => '...',
);

foreach( $links as $i => $link ) {
    print_r($link);
}
```